# Chrome Extension Textfield enter checking

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, enter

How do you check if the user of the extension presses ENTER while in a textfield (`search`), kind of like pressing a submit button but just pressing enter. I use the following code for button presses

```
//action listener
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', searchResult);
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', searchResult);
});
```

would I have to use somthing like`document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('enter', searchResult);`?

Comment: Capture keydown and check against keyCode 13, or wrap the elements in a form and use the submit event of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var searchElement = document.getElementById('search');

    searchElement.addEventListener('click', searchResult);
    searchElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            searchResult();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', searchResult);
});
```